# SolrException Unknown fieldtype

Tags: solr

I'm running into a problem that I can't seem to get past.  Whenever I start Solr I'm getting an error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown fieldtype 'int_us' specified on field partId
at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:501)
at org.apache.solr.shcema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:125)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:461)....
```

my schema.xml file looks like this:

```
<schema name="parts" version 1.5>
  <type>
    <fieldType name="text_en_US" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFacroty" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFacroty" language="English" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="string_en_US" class="solr.StrField"></fieldType>
    <fieldType name="int_us" class="solr.IntField"></fieldType>
  </type>
  <fields>
     <field name="partId" type="int_us" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" />
     <field name="partNumber" type="String_en_US" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" />
     <field name="desc" type="text_en_US" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
     <field name="usage" type="text_en_US" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
     <field name="qty" type="String_en_US" indexed="false" stored="true" required="true" />
     <field name="make" type="String_en_US" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
     <field name="year" type="int_us" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" />
   </fields>
</schema>
```

I have tried changing the fieldtype of partId, but I get the same error no matter what.
I am using solr 3.5 running on a tomcat 7 server.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  If this is not enough information please let me know and I'll post more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `<type>` to `<types>`

Comment: If we do this it will give error saying : schema.xml: field id: missing mandatory attribute 'type'

Comment: My answer was from 2012 so you are obviously using a newer version of solr https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's stackoverflow formatting but the posted schema is invalid xml

`<schema name="parts" version 1.5>`

should be

`<schema name="parts" version="1.5">`

Comment: I found the issue, it was a typo.  I had class="solr.phoneticFilter... instead of class="solr.PhoneticFilter.."  Sorry for not catching this before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with Solr 4.6 when I used

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Only root element correction to the `<types>` helped to resolve this issue.
This is first answer.